# Open a specific Command Promp with commands running

Tags: terminal, command, prompt

I'm using sass on my website and I find it annoying that I need to open every time  command prompt/terminal, type all the commands and then start my programming. How can I save a command prompt/terminal with the commands running. I'm using Windows 8 and Mac to program. Thanks for your help.

(The commands are [for commands prompt]:

```
cd xampp/htdocs
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

And [for Terminal]:

```
cd Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

Thank you a lot.)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this with success:

```
1. Create new text file on desktop;
2. Enter desired commands in text file;
3. Rename extension of text file from ".txt" --> ".bat"
```

Example, in bat file:

```
d:
cd server
node server.js
cmd
```